# Generalized integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I have this generalized integral:

$$
I := \int_2^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^a\log^b(x)}\,\text{d}x
$$

and I have to study the character as the real parameters vary $a,\,b$.

By substituting $t = \log(x)$ I returned to this other integral:

$$
I = \int_{\log(2)}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{(1-a)\,t}}{t^b}\,\text{d}t
$$

where it's clear that for $a<1$ the integrand isn't infinitesimal and therefore the integral diverges and that for $a=1$ we lead back to a sample integral that diverges if $b\le 1$, converges if $b > 1$.

Problems arise for $a > 1$ where I can only establish that:

$$
0 \le \frac{e^{(1-a)\,t}}{t^b} \le \frac{1}{t^b} \quad \quad \forall\,t \in [\log(2),\,+\infty)
$$

and therefore for the comparison criterion there's convergence for $b > 1$, but I cannot understand how to prove in a simple way that the integral also converges for $b \le 1$.

Comment: Try instead $t=[\log(x)]^b$ (this is what I would try). Do you know about the exponential integral function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we are trying to find:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha;\beta\right):=\int_2^\beta\frac{1}{x^\text{n}\ln^\alpha\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Frist, substitute $\text{u}=\ln\left(x\right)$ this gives:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\int_{\ln\left(2\right)}^{\ln\left(\beta\right)}\frac{\exp\left(\text{u}\left(1-\text{n}\right)\right)}{\text{u}^\alpha}\space\text{du}\tag2$$

Now, substitute $\text{v}=\text{u}^{1-\alpha}$ this gives:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\int_{\ln^{1-\alpha}\left(2\right)}^{\ln^{1-\alpha}\left(\beta\right)}\exp\left(\left(1-\text{n}\right)\text{v}^\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\right)\space\text{dv}\tag3$$

Now, substitute $\text{w}=\left(1-\text{n}\right)\text{v}^\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$ this gives:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\frac{\left(1-\text{n}\right)^{\alpha-1}}{1-\alpha}\int_{\left(1-\text{n}\right)\left(\ln^{1-\alpha}\left(2\right)\right)^\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}^{\left(1-\text{n}\right)\left(\ln^{1-\alpha}\left(\beta\right)\right)^\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}\exp\left(\text{w}^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}\right)\space\text{dw}\tag4$$

And the resulting integral is defined using the incomplete gamma function:

$$\int\exp\left(\text{w}^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}\right)\space\text{dw}=\left(\alpha-1\right)\left(-1\right)^{\alpha-1}\Gamma\left(1-\alpha,-\text{w}^\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\right)\tag5$$

So:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\left(-1\right)^\alpha\left(1-\text{n}\right)^{\alpha-1}\left[\Gamma\left(1-\alpha,-\text{w}^\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\right)\right]_{\left(1-\text{n}\right)\left(\ln^{1-\alpha}\left(2\right)\right)^\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}^{\left(1-\text{n}\right)\left(\ln^{1-\alpha}\left(\beta\right)\right)^\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}\tag6$$

Comment: How about the final substitutions?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I let the OP do that ;).